# Joomla JToolBarHelp

Tags: joomla, components, administrator

I am developing a Joomla component. I am trying to add a JToolBarHelp:

```
  JToolBarHelper::addNew('anadir');
  JToolBarHelper::editList('ver');
  JToolBarHelper::deleteList('vergrupos');
```

I declared the 'anadir' , 'ver' and 'vergrupos' functions in the controller:

```
  function ver() {
    $this->showView('ver');
  }

  function anadir() {
    $this->showView('anadir');
  }

  function vergrupos() {
    $this->showView('vergrupos');
  }
```

When I click the button, the page does not redirect. Why?

Comment: What version of Joomla are you using?

Comment: Are you adding your functions to the controller?

Comment: class XXController extends JController {
    private function showView($name) {
        JRequest::setVar('view', $name);
        JRequest::setVar('layout', 'default');
        parent::display();
    }

    function display() {
        $view = $_REQUEST['view'];
        if (strlen($view) == 0) {
            $view = 'ver';
        }
        $this->showView($view);
    }

    function ver() {
        $this->showView('ver');
    }

    function anadir() {
        $this->showView('anadir');
    }

    
    function vergrupos() {
        $this->showView('vergrupos');
    }

Comment: Please add you code to your question so it's easier to view. Also ensure you have read the Joomla Documentation for JToolbar ;)

Answer (score 0):

need to add name of controller name before the function you want to call

```
JToolBarHelper::addNew('controller.anadir');
JToolBarHelper::editList('controller.ver');
JToolBarHelper::deleteList('controller.vergrupos');
```

remove controller with name of controller in your case

Answer (score 0):

Add the JToolbar item like below: (this example is based on adding a new item to a list)

```
JToolBarHelper::custom('controller.anadir', 'new', 'new', 'New Anadir', false);
```

The false at the end lets joomla know that no additional selection is needed (checking a checkbox from a list to pass an ID or array of IDs)

You need to use the custom toolbar helper to add in a custom controller. Try that and see if it works then report back.